# Ruby Limit / Take / First - limit sometimes or ignore

Tags: ruby, middleman

I have the following method:

Now sometimes I want the limit attribute to be ignored

Therefore the .take method would be ignored, at the moment I do not know how to do this gracefully. As setting to nil errors the code.

Any help appreciated - new to ruby.

```
def articlesByCategory( category, extensions = [ "md" ], limit = 3 )

    # Check category is an array
    if !category.kind_of?(Array)
        category = [ category ]
    end

    # Create Return Array
    ret = []

    # Get the resources that are
    sitemap.resources.select { |r| ( category & Array( r.data.category ) ).present? }.take( limit ).each do |a|

        ret << a

    end

    # Return
    ret

end
```

Comment: It would be useful if we had sample input/output. This method could use some serious refactoring.

Comment: Input - articlesByCategory( "facebook", [ "md" ], nil ), out put is an array of posts from middleman

Comment: That’s not nearly useful enough. What is `sitemap.resources`? What is it’s `data.category`? Why is `extensions` passed in when it’s not used? Will `category` ever be an array? Will a resource’s `data.category` ever be an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code can be significantly refactored to do the same thing it’s doing now. There’s no need to do an `each` to build an exact copy of the array, and we can apply `Kernel#Array` to `category` the same way your did to `r.data.category`. Finally, `any?` reads a bit better (IMO) than `present?`, especially since the value cannot be `nil` (only caveat is if `nil` or `false` is a valid category).

```
def articles_by_category category, limit = 3
  category = Array(category)
  sitemap.resources.select do |resource|
    (Array(resource.data.category) & category).any?
  end.take(limit)
end
```

We can easily pull the `take` out into a conditional to get what you want:

```
def articles_by_category category, limit = 3
  category = Array(category)
  articles = sitemap.resources.select do |resource|
    (Array(resource.data.category) & category).any?
  end
  limit ? articles.take(limit) : articles
end
```

It might, however, make sense to just get rid of the limit entirely within the method and impose it externally. This is much more functional and keeps your method from doing a lot of things (what does a limit have to do with getting articles by category? (this method doesn’t even get articles by category, it gets whatever resources is (presumably articles…) for a given category)).

```
def articles_by_category category
  category = Array(category)
  sitemap.resources.select do |resource|
    (Array(resource.data.category) & category).any?
  end
end

articles_by_category('My Category').take(3)
```

Note that if category will never be an array (which seems likely given its singular name) than you can further simplify your method to:

```
def articles_by_category category
  sitemap.resources.select do |resource|
    resource.data.category == category
  end
end
```

(And of course add the `limit` feature back in if so desired.)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
category ||= []
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it like this in the end

```
def articlesByCategory( category, extensions = [ "md" ], limit = 3 )

    # Check category is an array
    if !category.kind_of?(Array)
        category = [ category ]
    end

    # Create Return Array
    ret = []

    # Get Resources
    resources = sitemap.resources.select { |r| ( category & Array( r.data.category ) ).present? }

    # Check limit is set
    if !limit.nil?
        resources = resources.take( limit )
    end

    # Get the resources that are
    resources.each do |a|

        ret << a

    end

    # Return
    ret

end
```